# React Native Functional Component Updates State On Second Submit Only

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks

When I console log my values, it updates only if I submit the form the second time. Why is this happening?

```
const Link = (props) => {
  const { state, scrape } = useContext(ScrapeContext);
  const [clipboard, setClipboard] = useState();
  const [googleClip, setGoogleClip] = useState(false);
  const [googleLink, setGoogleLink] = useState('');

  const urlFromClipboard = () => {
    Clipboard.getString().then((content) => {
      if (content.includes('https://www.google.com')){
        setGoogleClip(true);
        console.log('googleLink', googleLink);
        setClipboard(content);
        setGoogleLink(`${content.split('?')[0]}?__a=1`);
      } else {
        setGoogleClip(false);
      }
    });

    if (googleClip) {
      console.log(googleLink);
      scrape({ googleLink });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    urlFromClipboard();
    console.log('useEffect googleLink', googleLink);
    console.log('useEffect state', state);
  }, [clipboard]);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.inputFieldContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputField}
          placeholder='Enter Google url'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCorrect={false}
          value={googleClip ? clipboard : ''}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            urlFromClipboard();
          }}
          style={styles.touchSubmit}
        >
          <Text style={styles.touchText}>Submit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {state.errorMessage ? (
        <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{state.errorMessage}</Text>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```

What I have here is a component that will grab data from a url, and on submit it will scrape certain information the app needs, however, it will only update those console log values if I press the submit button twice.

Comment: you can directly referance your function like   <TouchableOpacity
  onPress={urlFromClipboard}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Bora Sumer mentioned, you're trying to use the state values before they are actually updated. You can do something like this:

```
    Clipboard.getString().then((content) => {
      if (content.includes('https://www.google.com')){

        let link = `${content.split('?')[0]}?__a=1`
        setGoogleClip(true);
        console.log('googleLink', googleLink);
        setClipboard(content);
        setGoogleLink(link);
        console.log(link);
        scrape({ googleLink: link });

      } else {
        setGoogleClip(false);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here that you do not have access the state right after you set the state. So you actually set the state, and it is there, but you only see the updated state second time you run the console log. That does not mean that you have to submit twice but when you submit for second time you run the console.log for the second time and see the value. Because setting state functions are async.In this case, you need to use callback function to actually see the updated state on the console. Hope that helps.

Comment: How do you do a callback in state hooks? is it just useEffect? and add `googleLink` and `state` into the callback array? ie: `[clipboard, googleLink, state]`? If I did it this way, my console log will keep executing in an infinite loop. I thought useEffect would only run once

Comment: @hellomello there's no official way to do callback after setState but if you really want to see your `googleClip` after setState, you can add a `<Text>{googleClip}<Text/>` in your `View`

Comment: And `googleClip` is actually `content` so you can simply do `console.log(content)` right before `setClipboard(content);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await each time you setState like following:

```
const urlFromClipboard = () => {
Clipboard.getString().then( async (content) => {
  if (content.includes('https://www.google.com')){
    await setGoogleClip(true);
    console.log('googleLink', googleLink);
    await setClipboard(content);
    await setGoogleLink(`${content.split('?')[0]}?__a=1`);
  } else {
    await setGoogleClip(false);
  }
 });

 if (googleClip) {
    console.log(googleLink);
    scrape({ googleLink });
 }
}
```